# PHP copy does not copy even with permissions at 777

Tags: php

I have some php code that takes a zip file, extracts it into ../images/galleries/foldername/zipfilename and now I am trying to take the files that are extracted back a level into the foldername folder, I am changing the permissions on both folders and each file that is extracted and the files still wont copy :(

I am getting no errors at all, even with errors turned on.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($path) === true) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $zip->extractTo('../images/galleries/' . $galleryName, array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));
    }
    $zip->close();
    chmod('../images/galleries/' . $galleryName . '/' . $name[0], 0777);
    chmod('../images/galleries/' . $galleryName, 0777);
    foreach(glob('../images/galleries/' . $galleryName . '/' . $name[0] . '/*') as $image){
        chmod($image, 0777);
        copy($image, '../images/galleries/' . $galleryName . '/');
    }
}
```

What am doing wrong? As of right now, the zip gets uploaded and files get extracted into foldername and another folder is created with the items inside that folder, I really need to get those items in foldername.

I am turning on my php errors via `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

and the permissions are being changed to 0777

or if someone knows a better way to use extractTo better so the image is in foldername and not zipfilename

Comment: As a general rule, you cannot grant to yourself the permissions you lack. It'd be like being able to get a key for any lock.

Comment: BTW, how have you verified that errors are turned on? What PHP directives have you set and how do you know the change has been effective?

Comment: the permissions on the folders and files are being changed to 0777

Comment: Then you most likely have access to those files and folders and don't need to change their file system bits.

Comment: Are you logging errors or displaying them?

Comment: trying to display errors via `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: A `chmod($image,0777)` cannot work unless you already own  the file. You need permissions on the destination folder. Access may be denied by your server configuration not just file system permissions.

Comment: Well, that directive sets a filter for error messages but doesn't decide whether they're displayed or logged. Please have a look at the `display_errors` directive. When I want to ensure I get error messages I often just make one purpose :)

Comment: Can you do the exact same process, that you do in your code, by hand (i.e. step by step manually)? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: after running this script, have you verified that the permissions are in fact 777?

Comment: Are you sure you are not `umask`-ed? That would nullify your attempt to extend permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line seems wrong

```
copy($image, '../images/galleries/' . $galleryName . '/');
```

`copy()` requires a filename for the destination, refer to the [first comment on the related PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

To get the filename you could do something like

```
$filename = end(explode('/', $image));
```

Or you could generate a new one with the same extension which you can also get using the two methods above.

Furthermore if all you want is to move the images and do not need to keep two copies, you might want to take a look at [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) instead, as stated on the doc.